# Reading a File through get, getline and read : C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to explore ifstream class and have written below code which reads a file `Test.txt`

*'Test.txt'* - Content

```
This is Line One
This is Line Two
This is Line Three
This is Line Four
This is Line Five
```

Code Written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char buff[50];

    char ch;
    ifstream is("test.txt");
    if (!is)
    cout << "Unable to open " << endl;

    while(is)
    {
        ch=(char)is.get();
        if(ch != EOF)//If EOF is not checked then
        //EOF converted as a char is displyed as
        // last char of the file
        cout << ch;
        }


    cout << "\n\n###########\n\n";
    is.clear(); //clearing ios_base::eofbit which was set 
    //in previous action
    is.seekg(0,ios_base::beg); //Going back to start of File

   while(is)
   {

     is.get(buff,50,'\n');
     cout << buff ;
     cout << "\n--------------\n";
     is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
     //Flushing the is stream as '\n' was left by get fn
   }


  cout << "\n\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n\n";
    is.clear();
    is.seekg(0,ios_base::beg);

    while(!is.eof())
    {
        is.getline(buff,50,'\n');
        cout << buff;
        cout << "\n--------------\n";
        //No need to flush the is stream as '\n' 
        //was extracted and discarded by getline
        }

    cout << "\n\n$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n\n";
    is.clear();
    is.seekg(0,ios_base::end);
    int size=is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0,ios_base::beg);
    cout << "size : " << size << endl;

    //char* readBuff = (char *) ::operator new(sizeof(char)*size);
    char* readBuff = new char[size];
    is.read(readBuff,size);
    cout << readBuff;
    delete(readBuff);

    is.close();

    return 0;
    }
```

OutPut:

```
Gaurav@Gaurav-PC /cygdrive/d/Trial
$ ./Trial
This is Line One
This is Line Two
This is Line Three
This is Line Four
This is Line Five

###########

This is Line One
--------------
This is Line Two
--------------
This is Line Three
--------------
This is Line Four
--------------
This is Line Five
--------------


@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

This is Line One
--------------
This is Line Two
--------------
This is Line Three
--------------
This is Line Four
--------------
This is Line Five
--------------


$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

size : 92
This is Line One
This is Line Two
This is Line Three
This is Line Four
This is Line Five▒u
```

There are some issues which I want to ask and get clarified:

**1) When I use `get` as below**

```
   while(is)
   {

     is.get(buff,50,'\n');
     cout << buff ;
    // cout << "\n--------------\n";
     is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
     //Flushing the is stream as '\n' was left by get fn
   }
```

i.e. I commented out `cout << "\n--------------\n";` then the file is read as

```
###########

This is Line Fivee
```

i.e. it misses first four lines and reads only last one with extra `'e'` .. not able to figure out why so ?

**2) When I use `getline` as below:**

```
// while(!is.eof())
   while(is)
    {
        is.getline(buff,50,'\n');
        cout << buff;
        cout << "\n--------------\n";
        //No need to flush the is stream as '\n'
        //was extracted and discarded by getline
        }
```

i.e. I used `while(is)` instead of `while(!is.eof())` - I got the output:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

This is Line One
--------------
This is Line Two
--------------
This is Line Three
--------------
This is Line Four
--------------
This is Line Five
--------------

--------------
```

i.e. after the last line I get two extra lines. Again not able to figure out why so?

**3) With `read` function** the size I am getting is `92` where as total number of charaters in the file is `89` including `EOF`,`spaces` and `'\n'`. Also the last line shows two garbage characters after rearing the last character of the file. Why such behavior?

```
cout << "\n\n$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n\n";
is.clear();
is.seekg(0,ios_base::end);
int size=is.tellg();
is.seekg(0,ios_base::beg);
cout << "size : " << size << endl;

//char* readBuff = (char *) ::operator new(sizeof(char)*size);
char* readBuff = new char[size];
is.read(readBuff,size);
cout << readBuff;
delete(readBuff);
```

OutPut:

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

size : 92
This is Line One
This is Line Two
This is Line Three
This is Line Four
This is Line Five▒u
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As Per Answer received by Mats Peterson , I tried below code:

```
while(is.get(buff,50,'\n'))
   {
     cout << buff ;
     //cout << "\n--------------\n";
     is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
     //Flushing the is stream as '\n' was left by get fn
   }


  cout << "\n\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n\n";
    is.clear();
    is.seekg(0,ios_base::beg);

   // while(!is.eof())
   while(is.getline(buff,50,'\n'))
    {

        cout << buff;
        //cout << "\n--------------\n";
        //No need to flush the is stream as '\n'
        //was extracted and discarded by getline
        }
```

But got the output:

```
###########

This is Line Fivee

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

This is Line Fivee
```

i.e Only Last line read... if I uncomment `//cout << "\n--------------\n";` I get proper reading

**@Down Votes** At least comment what made you do so? I faced this issue that is why asked here to gain more insight from experts..

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @MatsPetersson exactly my guess :)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes Windows 7 and Using Cygwin..

Comment: For the last one you will have to create a buffer that is `size+1` characters so you have enough room for the terminating `null` character.

Comment: @KristerAndersson But `read` does not give null terminated string... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/  `This function simply copies a block of data, without checking its contents nor appending a null character at the end.`

Comment: @GauravK - Yes it does, but the buffer must still be null terminated, so you could do `buffer[size] = 0;` after your `read` operation.

Comment: @KristerAndersson `char* readBuff = new char[size+1];` resolved the issue.. But I am confused - why to make it `size+1`

Comment: @GauravK - That is because the you will need one more byte for the null character. The size of the data you're about to read + 1.

Comment: None of your code checks the return value of input operations.

Comment: @KristerAndersson http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/  the example also does not use `length+1`

Comment: @KerrekSB `while(!is.eof())` is checking if `eofbit` is set or not?

Comment: @GauravK - No, but in the example they are not outputting the contents of the buffer, it is for that purpose you'll need the terminating null character. If you will use the read data as a string it should be terminated by a null character.

Comment: @GauravK: I don't care. What I said, and what matters, is that you never check the result of *input* operations, such as `get`, `getline` or `read`. The `eof()` check is a red herring that's virtually useless.

Comment: @KerrekSB How to check the return value ? Any sample code u can refer ?

Comment: @GauravK: 1) read the manual to figure out what the return value *is* and what it means (it's different for each of the functions), 2) check any of the *thousands* of similar questions on this website. The typical idiom is `while (std::getline(is, line)) { /* ... */ }` or `while (is >> x) { /* ... */ }`; the return value is immediately evaluated in a boolean context. By the way, the same goes for C-library functions like `scanf` and `fgets`. Basically, you must never attempt to consume alleged input data before you're certain that the input operation which produced it succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

In the first two questions, you are because you are reading "one more than you have", which is a typical consequence of "the failure state is not set until we have tried to read past the end". This is why you should use

```
 while(is.get(... ))
 while(is.getline(...))
```

as the condtions for ending loops - because that will not run the loop when the read fails.

The third issue is because Windows used "CR+LF" for newlines, where reading a file in text mode (which is the default) collapses these into a single newline character. So the size of your file according to `is.tellg` is larger by one character for each newline than the data you actually read. You can use `is.gcount()` to see how many characters you ACTUALLY read. (and `if (!is.read(... )) actual = is.gcount(); else actual = size;` should give you a complete piece of code).

Comment: `while(is.get(buff,50,'\n'))` or `while(is.getline(buff,50,'\n'))` produces same result

Comment: Really? Can you edit your post and add your "new improved" code to the bottom, please? I'm pretty sure my answer is correct, so there's two possible scenarios - the C++ library you are using is bad (very unlikely) or there is something else wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reason of reading extra value or line which is termed as garbage value (i thinks it so) because of use of eof ( you have used it) . when we used it, for ex, to read a character from a file, then it reads  the character but because file does'nt end as well loop does'nt end at point, so it again reads extra value from file. so main thing which i want to say is that avoid function eof in any looping statement untill to end the file reading and not in any input-output conditions.